# Application independent of database schema

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have an asp.net application that uses the entity framework to interact with the database.

In the new version that I am working on now, I need to separate the application from the database so that it can be used with a variety of databases that have similar data but different schemas. (Able to be used for new clients)

So far this is my approach, but it feels wrong

- I have objects from a data entity model generated by the clients database
- I custom wrote objects that my system will use
- I wrote an interface that outlines all of the data operations that return my custom objects
- I wrote an implementation of the interface that takes my client's objects from the entity framework connected to their database, and loads the fields I want into my custom objects.

This feels wrong as now I have 2 sets of similar objects.

Example, here I get `salesOrders` from the clients database, and dump the data into my custom `Job` object:

```
public List<Job> getJobs()
{

    List<Job> jobs = new List<Job>();

    using (var context = new TBDIEntities.TBDIEntities())
    {
        //get all future events that are not cancelled
        List<SalesOrder> salesOrders = context.SalesOrders
            .Where(c => c.EVENTCONFIRMATION != "CANCELLED" && c.FUNCTIONDATE >= DateTime.Now)
            .ToList<SalesOrder>();

        jobs.AddRange(from order in salesOrders
                        let dateTime = order.FUNCTIONSTARTTIME
                        where dateTime != null
                        select new Job
                        {
                            Description = order.FUNCTIONTYPE,
                            StartTime = (DateTime)dateTime,
                            Id = order.SALESORDERREF_TXNID.ToString(),
                            ShiftGroups = new List<ShiftGroup>(),
                            Status = order.EVENTCONFIRMATION,
                            ShiftCount = (int)context.BSS_ShiftListView
                                .Count(c => c.SALESORDERREF_TXNID == order.SALESORDERREF_TXNID),
                            ConfirmedShifts = (int)context.BSS_ShiftListView
                                .Count(c => c.SALESORDERREF_TXNID == order.SALESORDERREF_TXNID && c.Confirmed != null),
                            Client = new Client { Name = order.CustomerRef_FullName }
                        });
    }

    return jobs;
}
```

So I am creating a new context, getting a collection of `salesOrders` (the table name in the clients database), then taking the the data from the `salesOrders` and creating new `Job` objects (the ones I wrote that my application will interact with) and returning the `Job` objects.

This feels wrong as now I have 2 lists of similar objects (`SalesOrders` and `Jobs`), and I have to write CRUD operations for each object rather than just using the entity framework.

Example, I have a page where you can add new shifts. But the `Shifts` table will be different from client to client, and changes I make need to update the clients table. So how do I write code that can use shifts, but can have the entity framework swapped out with schemas from new clients? I need things like shifts to be in a collection that I can use to databind an `asp:ListView`.

What is the smartest way of doing this? How do I use the entity framework but be independent of customer schema so my project can be reused for many databases?

Comment: You'd have to elaborate more on actual differences between databases.

Comment: Lets say I have 2 clients. One has an Employee table and one has a Staff table. Both have similar data but different column names. For my application my code needs to work with a staff object that has x number of fields. 

How can I write my program using my own staff object and be able to swap out an entity model for client 1 with an entity model for client 2? This is with the aim of being able to use this one application for several clients that all have different databases and need my application to work directly on their data.

ex. a method that returns all staff not working in a timeframe

Comment: This sounds like you could use the code first approach and use the fluent configuration api conditionally (if client1, if client2). The fluent api lets you control the mapping, which class maps to which database, which property maps to which column. I haven't tried that but you shouldn't have issues targeting multiple schemas in the same application.

Answer (score 1):

Your two similar objects are really performing two different roles for your architectural layers and are not redundant. What you're working with are Domain Models (`SalesOrders`), Data Transfer Objects, and View Models (`Jobs`). So you really might end up with 3 sets of objects.

A tool like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) takes out much of the pain of the tedious object-to-object mapping.